# Why is the following recurrent sequence convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a, b , c, d$ be reals. Define the sequence $(x_n)$ as:

$$x_0 = a,\,\, x_1 = b$$
$$x_n = \left(1 - \frac{b^2}{n^2}\right)x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}^{-1} (x_{k+1}-x_k)(c\, x_{n-k-1}- d\, x_{n-k-2}),\,\,\, n \geq2.$$
I want to prove that $(x_n)$ is convergent.
Here are two examples for different values of $(a, b , c, d).$
[image]
[image]

It seems (after several numerical tests) that the sequence is bounded and monotone from specific $n_0.$ The boundness of the sequence imply that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}^{-1} (x_{k+1}-x_k)(c\, x_{n-k-1}- d\, x_{n-k-2})$$
is bounded and the term with the sum goes to zero.

Thank you for any hint

Comment: And the question actually is ?

Comment: I assume the question is whether the sequence is convergent and how to show/determine this.

Comment: The question is: Why is the sequence convergent ?

Comment: I have a problem with your sequence definition versus the example graph plots. For example, for $a=1,b=.5,c=1,d=2$ I get $x_2=.61875$ but your plot shows $x_2\approx .52$ and for $a=2,b=-2,c=.5,d=2.5$ I get $x_2=4.8$ but your plot shows $x_2\approx1.3$

Comment: @Somos I might took different constants. I can check again, but this won't change the result that the sequence converges. I guess you found in your plots that the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Yes, it looks oscillating at first, and then monotone convergence but still, to remove doubts, please use correct constants.

Answer (score 4):

Given two sequences $a_n,b_n$, denote by $a_n\lesssim b_n$ if $|a_n|\le Mb_n$ holds for every $n$ for some $M<\infty$, which is possibly dependent on $a,b,c,d$.

Let
$$T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}^{-1} (x_{k+1}-x_k)(c\, x_{n-k-1}- d\, x_{n-k-2}),n\ge 2$$

and

$X_n=\max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}$

Observe that, since $\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}^{-1}\lesssim \frac{1}{n^3}$ for $1\le k\le n-2$,

$$|T_n|\lesssim \frac{1}{n}X_{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{n^3}X_{n-1}^2$$

and correspondingly,

$$X_n-X_{n-1}\le|x_n-x_{n-1}|\lesssim \frac{1}{n^2}X_{n-1}$$

Since $\prod_{j=1}^\infty (1+M/j^2)<\infty$ for every $M<\infty$, you can notice that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n<\infty$, which implies the boundedness of $\{x_n\}$.

Now, since

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n-x_{n-1}|\lesssim\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}X_{n-1}\lesssim \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

, $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

Comment: +1. Marvelous proof!

Comment: But what about the monotonicity of the sequence after a finite index?

Comment: @Hans - Actually, I expect that we can show eventual monotonicity when $(a-b)(c-d)+2b^2\neq 0$ (needs some check though). However, since this is not the main question of the OP and this is not a full result, I did not mention it here.

Comment: I would very much like to see your proof of that.

Comment: @C.Park Is there a "square" missing in the estimate 
$X_n-X_{n-1}\le|x_n-x_{n-1}|\lesssim \frac{1}{n^2}X_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: @C.Park Would you please check !?

Comment: @A.PI - it seems to be a serious mistake I made... the problem now reduces to showing boundedness (from above) of $Z_n-n$ from the sequence $Z_n=\max_{0<j<n}\{Z_{n-j}+Z_j-j\}-2\log n+C$, where $C$ is a fixed constant, and  $Z_1$ is a given number, which is probably much easier, but I think I need to consider this problem a bit (that is, possibly I won't be able to resolve..) If you have any idea on this, it would be thankful to tell me that. / I apologize for making such a mistake in an answer.

Comment: I am looking forward to the corrected proof!

Comment: @C.Park ... no worry, you already gave a nice effort. I tried to do some numerics on the conjecture you made in your last comment  about $Z_n -n.$ It seems that such sequence is bounded from above for specific cases of $C$ and $Z_1.$ Take counterwise, for example, $Z_1 = 7$ and $C =0.$

Comment: Any new progress on correcting this proof?

Comment: @Hans Thank you for asking. I guess we need to start a new bounty :D

Comment: @A.PI: I guess. :-)

Comment: @A.PI: Maybe you should post this question on mathoverflow.net. Please let me know the link if you do post the question there.

Comment: @Hans I didn't post it there.

Comment: @A.PI: I am suggesting that you should post your question there because that site targets more experienced professional mathematicians who have a higher probability of giving a correct answer.

Comment: @Hans I've just posted it there

Comment: @A.PI: As I have suggested above, it would be good for the audience that you post the link to your question on mathoverflow.net.